# Laravel Passing Variable from a controller to another Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to pass a variable from a controller to another controller I tried using

```
Redirect::to('dashboard/'.$ssid.'/')->with(compact('wname'))
```

but does not work any idea how can I achieve this?

here is my code

Route

```
Route::get('dashboard/{ssid}/', 'HomeController@showDash');
```

LoginController

```
public function post_index()
  {

  if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
    $users = User::where('username','=',$email)->get();
      foreach ($users as $value):
        $activated = $value['a_status'];
        $wname = $value['wholename'];

      endforeach;

      if($activated == 1):
          $red= Redirect::to('dashboard/'.$ssid.'/')->with(compact('wholename')); 
      else:
          $red= View::make('login');
      endif;
      return $red;
}

 }
```

HomeController

```
public function showDash($ssid,$wholename)
{
 foreach ($wholename as $userVal):
        $fn = $userVal['firstname'];
        $ln = $userVal['lastname'];
     endforeach;
return View::make('dashboard')->with(compact('fn'));

}
```

The error I'm having is that `Missing argument 2 for HomeController::showDash()` as per laravel's debugger..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer based on the comments:

```
public function post_index()
{

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
    $users = User::where('username','=',$email)->get();
    foreach ($users as $value){
        $activated = $value['a_status'];
        $wname = $value['wholename'];
    }
    if($activated == 1) {
        Redirect::to('dashboard/'.$ssid.'/')->with(['wholename' => $wholename]); 
    }

    return View::make('login');
}


public function showDash($ssid)
{
    $wholename = (Session::has('wholename')) ? Session::get('wholename') : [];
    foreach ($wholename as $userVal) {
        $fn = $userVal['firstname'];
        $ln = $userVal['lastname'];
    }
    return View::make('dashboard')->with(compact('fn'));
}
```

Everything else can stay as is.

**Update:** fixed erroneous space in 'whole name' (autocorrect did that, sorry).

Comment: hmm but the `$wholename` would then be visible on the addressbar.. I'm trying to hide it thats why I'm tried using `with()`..

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case you need to pull the variable from the session, it won't be passed in the method call.

So: 
$wholename = (Session::has('whole name')) ? Session::get('wholename') : [];
right above the foreach should do it, and remove the $wholename parameter from the method signature.

Comment: sorry I'm new to laravel how do I use session in laravel?

Comment: using ->with(...) adds it to the session. I will update my answer above.

Comment: I see so what I  did was actually a  session... but that didnt work.. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It returns me a null I replaced your [] with NULL to check because for somereason it does not return me values